# Get different window size of what I set in Kivy/Python

Tags: python, kivy

I want to set my window size with kivy to [500, 250]. The resize works, but the size I obtain is not exactly the one given in input. I instead obtain something around 637px in length (after measurement + widget size comparison).

Here is my code to set the window size, but note that different values correctly change the ratio.

`Window.size = tuple(config.WDIM)  # where WDIM = [500, 250]`